# join an array of elements to append it to a node

Tags: javascript

How can I do something like:

```
 var html = [];
 var tr = document.createElement('tr');
 var tr_two = document.createElement('tr');
 var tr_three = document.createElement('tr');
 html.push(tr);
 html.push(tr_two);
 html.push(tr_three);

 html.join(''); //This doesnt work

 document.getElementById('tbody').appendChild(html);
```

So I need to join my array in a way that is doable, so I hit the DOM once.

Comment: `//This doesnt work` what do you mean? do you get an error?

Comment: join will only work on array of strings.

Comment: console.log(html);

Comment: iterate the array `html` and append content of all the indices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
 var tbody = document.getElementById('tbody');
 html.forEach(funtion(node) {
     tbody.appendChild(node);
 });
```

Comment: yeah this would be the default option, however, I'm looking for a way to hit the dom only once

Comment: Then I thin the only other way is innerHTML and stringify the nodes.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to join `DOM` elements instead strings.

You can use `outerHTML` to achive what you want.

```
 var html = [];
 var tr = document.createElement('tr');
 var tr_two = document.createElement('tr');
 var tr_three = document.createElement('tr');
 html.push(tr.outerHTML);
 html.push(tr_two.outerHTML);
 html.push(tr_three.outerHTML);


 html.join(''); //Now it will work
```

And to append to DOM use

```
document.getElementById('tbody').innerHTML += html.join('');
```

Comment: And to append to DOM use `document.getElementById('tbody').innerHTML += html.join('');`

Comment: awesome! but what if I have a button? the join(' ') is not working prepertly I think

Answer (score 0):

The appendChild() function can only be used with nodes, not strings. To do that with your current code, change it to the following:

```
var html = [];
var tr = document.createElement('tr').appendChild(document.createTextNode("tr 1"));
var tr_two = document.createElement('tr').appendChild(document.createTextNode("tr 2"));
var tr_three = document.createElement('tr').appendChild(document.createTextNode("tr 3"));

html.push(tr);
html.push(tr_two);
html.push(tr_three);

var tbody = document.getElementById("tbody");

html.forEach(function(elem) {
    tbody.appendChild(elem);
})
```

I've added text nodes to each of the `tr`s created so you can see the difference between each one.

The `forEach` loop just iterates over each element in array you created, and appends each one at time to the element you specified.

[Here's a JSFiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/pinjasaur/mvs7xyLm/)